# How to find the amount of a transition from each row in a column?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I am currently analyzing a data in python from NBA stats which contains a data pretty much like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6Jbv.png)

The expected result would be something like:
Missed Shot -> Missed Shot = A, 
Missed Shot -> Made Shot = B,
Made Shot -> Missed Shot = C,
Made Shot -> Made Shot =D

With A, B, C,and D is the amount of each transition from the data. Is there any way to count the amount of A,B,C and D?

Comment: can you give a reproducible example?

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you gave a reproducible example, but something on the line of:

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

```
yourtable.groupby(['yourcolumA', 'yourcolumnB']).sum()
```

would do the job.